# Nodejs: instanceof behaviour fails / issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

In one of my company's product running on node v4.0, there is a class, say `ClassA`, which I import in use in many places using require, but then, there is a place where I check if an object is of type ClassA, which it is, but the check fails

**NOTE:** The main issue is, **it does not always fail**, objects created in some modules return true, but from other modules return false. Interestingly ( when checked with node-inspector), Object.getPrototypeof(object) returns 'ClassA' for all objects.

someClass.js:

```
var ClassA = require('./classA.js')
...
objA instanceof ClassA // should return true, but returns false for objects created in some modules
```

I am guessing the reason is require is not caching ClassA correctly, what can be the solution?

ClassA code is like:

```
function A(){...}

module.exports = A; // and the usage is like var obj = new ClassA();
```

Comment: Please add classA.js code

Comment: @AmiramKorach ClassA code is not the issue, because in some places, instanceof works, and in some places it doesn't, but added pseudo code anyway

Comment: In all places, do you init the object (like objA) in the same manner?

Comment: Your pseudo code doesn't exhibit the described behaviour. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: have you trued to delete _ClassA_ from cache? `delete require.cache[moduleName]`

Comment: How you create `objA` - is it like `objA = new ClassA`?

Comment: to answer I need to see your classA constructor, and your require path.
Since Instanceof is returning false then ClassA must be undef.

Comment: @OsamaSalama updated question. But, ClassA constructor is not the issue, I am guessing the issue is closer to how node handles modules, than the code itself, that's the main reason I wanted to put in as little code as possible.

Comment: @robertklep I feel that, this is more of an abstract issue of how node handles modules and classes defined in them, hence I provided as little code as possible. For now, solved it by using duck typing, but thought of posting a general question, answer to which might help others in future.

Comment: @mido since it only happens for some modules and not for others, I doubt it has anything to do with Node per se. I think there's something in your code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @mido Apart from the `instanceof` returning false, what other problems are you facing with extending this type ?

Comment: "*I am guessing the reason is require is not caching ClassA correctly*" - yes, that sounds likely (or maybe you are creating instances of `ClassA` before having completely initialised it - are there any circular references in your modules?). However, we cannot tell you the solution if you don't show us the faulty code. Please post the code where you create the class and where you instantiate the objects.